# Unwrapping SCNVector3/SCNVector4 values to print?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

This should be an easy question

```
   import SceneKit
    import Accelerate

    var str:SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(1, 2, -8)
    println("vector \(str)"
```

answer

```
vector C.SCNVector3
```

How to unwrap and display the vector like [ 1, 2, -8]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update for Swift 2:** In Swift 2, structures are by default printed
with all properties:

```
let str = SCNVector3Make(1, 2, -8)
print("vector \(str)")
// Output:
// vector SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: -8.0)
```

You can customize the output by adopting the `CustomStringConvertible`
protocol:

```
extension SCNVector3 : CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "[\(x), \(y), \(z)]"
    }
}

let str = SCNVector3Make(1, 2, -8)
print("vector \(str)")
// Output:
// vector [1.0, 2.0, -8.0]
```

---

*Previous answer:*

As Eric already explained, `println()` checks if the object conforms
to the `Printable` protocol. You can add conformance for `SCNVector3`
with a custom extension:

```
extension SCNVector3 : Printable {
    public var description: String {
        return "[\(self.x), \(self.y), \(self.z)]"
    }
}

var str = SCNVector3Make(1, 2, -8)
println("vector \(str)")
// Output:
// vector [1.0, 2.0, -8.0]
```

Comment: Printable has been renamed to CustomStringConvertible. Thanks for the snippet!

Comment: @Crashalot: You are completely right, I have updated the answer. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @MartinR you have educated more people than you realize on SO. no need to thank anyone; we all need to thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you go and look at the definition of SCNVector3 you will see that its a struct and doesn't have any methods to print nicely like you want. A struct in Swift that prints out a description would conform to the [Printable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html) protocol.

Since this struct doesn't do it for you, print out each component individually:

```
println("Vector: [\(str.x), \(str.y), \(str.z)]")
```

Output: Vector: [1.0, 2.0, -8.0]

Comment: Thanks this will work but I was looking to vectorize the print inline like perl.